# items by site query via QB API

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

In QBSDK12 there was special request ItemSitesQueryRq, so, for example, there was possibility to get QuantityonHand by Site for every item.
Is exists way to request such information about items by sites (warehouses) via Intuit API for QBD?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

'SITE' attribute is not available in QBD API.

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0600_object_reference/item

So, it is not possible to query 'QuantityonHand' by Site for every item.

Thanks

Comment: Is it in plan to add this attribute?

Comment: It will not be added in V2.
In V3 also, this attribute is not mentioned in API docs.
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v3/030_entity_services_reference/item

Thanks.